# Java BigInteger toByteArray specify number of bytes to use

Tags: java, biginteger

I was wondering it there is any way to specify how many bytes to use when creating the byte array using toByteArray method. For example:

```
BigInteger bigInteger = new BigInteger("-12");
```

I want `bigInteger.toByteArray()` to return an array with values `FF` and `F4` (assuming that the value is represented using 4 bytes - short variable, but it returns only `F4`.

Comment: It is unlikely it returns `FF`, because that would be `-1`. In any case, the answer to your question is "no", as the [documentation says](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigInteger.html#toByteArray()) _"The array will contain the minimum number of bytes required to represent this BigInteger"_

Comment: If you check the documentation it is going to use the minimum number of bytes to represent the value as a signed twos complement integer. -12 can be represented by 2 bytes. Really suprising you get `FF` maybe you should include the code to check the value.

Comment: Sorry, it should have been F4. I edited now.

Comment: You can always sign-extend the number yourself: Just repeat the most significant bit until you get a bytestring of the desired length.

Comment: I could understand this if there was a binary two's complement feature since a width might be necessary.  But why would *you* want to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could just make your own helper class.

```
public class BigIntegerHelper {

    public static byte[] toByteArray(BigInteger big, int minLength) {
        byte[] base=big.toByteArray();
        byte[] returnArray=new byte[Math.max(base.length, minLength)];
        if ((base[0]&128)!=0) {
            Arrays.fill(returnArray, (byte) 0xFF);
        }
        System.arraycopy(base,0,returnArray,returnArray.length-base.length,base.length);
        return returnArray;
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

It's unclear exactly what you're going for but [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigInteger.html) has a [`shortValue()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Number.html#shortValue()) method that might help.

For example,

```java
BigInteger big = new BigInteger("-12");
short s = big.shortValue();
byte [] bytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(2).putShort(s).array();
```

Something similar can be done if you want 4 bytes (int) or 8 bytes(long).